# What field type would give a better index perfomance in oracle db?

Tags: oracle

I have a field that contains time of order creation(order_time). Naturally, the best data type for that field is TIMESTAMP, but I want to create index and I'm not sure that TIMESTAMP index would be better than any numerical index. What's the best practice here?
I'm using oracle database

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference, performance wise. Probably an index on a timestamp would be bigger than on a simple numeric column. But this is all irrelevant: the decision depends on your business and app needs, not index size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use the most appropriate data-type for the data:

- If the data has date and time components and has a time-zone then use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`;
- If the data has date and time components with fractional seconds and no time-zone then use `TIMESTAMP`;
- If the data has date and time components with no fractional seconds and no time-zone then use `DATE`; and
- If your data is an instant measured, for example, as the number of milliseconds (or seconds) since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC and you almost entirely use it in its numeric form (i.e. you never, or very rarely, convert it to a human readable format such as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF`) then you may want to store it as a number. However, if you want to format it so it is readable or compare it to dates then you should prefer the `TIMESTAMP` (or `DATE`) data type.

**Never** use an inappropriate data-type for your column. The index performance between the different data-types should be mostly irrelevant and the overheads of converting from an inappropriate data-type to an appropriate one are likely to be a much more significant cost.